# Function return type mismatch phenomenon when returning different input ranges

Tags: templates, d

I get this error: `Error: mismatched function return type inference of` when I return different type of InputRanges from within the same function. The type returned by `take` or `takeExactly` is for some reason compatible with the original input range, but not compatible with my custom input range.

```
auto decode(Range)(Range r) {
  if (r.front == 0) {        
    r.popFront();
    return r;
  } else if (r.front == 1) {
    r.popFront();
    return r.take(3); // this is compatible with the return type above
  } else if (r.front == 2) {
    r.popFront();
    return MyRange(r); // this is not compatible with the types above
  }
}
```

What's going on?

Comment: Are `MyRange` has slicing (`opSlice`)?

Comment: Yes, it has slicing.

Comment: So practically that's the answer: r and r.take(3) has the same type if the range support slicing, and it's different from MyRange(r). Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `template Take(R)` wouldn't change anything to the message error you get from the compiler. The problem is that the return type varies in a function that only works at run-time.

Different return types could only be inferred at compile time but in this case `r.front` value wouldn't be known.

To simplify here is an example that gets rid of the ranges and reproduces the problem

```
// t can be tested at compile-time, fun is a template
auto fun(int t)()
{
    static if (t == 0) return "can be inferred";
    else return new Object; 
}

// t cant be tested at compile-time and this produces your error:
// Error: mismatched function return type inference of typethis and that 
auto notfun(int t)
{
    if (t == 0) return "cant be inferred";
    else return new Object; 
}

void main(string[] args)
{
    import std.stdio;
    fun!0().writeln; // works, returns a string
    fun!1().writeln; // works, returns an int
}
```

Finally what you have two choices:

- find a common type
- test `r.front` out of the function and call different overload according to the value.

Comment: Thanks, I got rid of the Alias part of the question. This what you are saying make sense, but doesn't explain why both `return r;` and `return r.take(3)` works in the same function. It's because what sigoit has pointed out: it's a range that supports slicing, therefore it's the same type.